# Limit copssh users to home directory Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, sftp, file-permissions, copssh

I have found these two sites below:
[CopSSH SFTP -- limit users access to their home directory only](https://serverfault.com/questions/132331/copssh-sftp-limit-users-access-to-their-home-directory-only) and http://blogs.windowsnetworking.com/wnadmin/2006/11/07/copssh-restricting-users-access/ as well as the Copssh website, but upon completion they do not seem to work.

I have copssh installed and I have a separate Windows account "sftpuser" created that is used to connect. The connection works just fine, but I want to limit that user to just their home directory and sub folders.

I have 3 hard drives, the C:, a W: and an S: and I want the FTP account to only be able to access the W: drive and its contents (the root of the W: drive is the FTP home directory).

Right now "sftpuser" can access all folders, including jump drives to C:, and S:.

The linked tutorials do not seem to work, because it seems when I create a group "ftpusersgroup" and add "sftpuser" to the group, and then deny "ftpusersgroup" access to the C: drive, the service breaks and I can no longer login.

I have undone everything and am ready to start fresh. Does anyone know how to do this, or is there a better tutorial that someone has or has found?

I hope this makes sense. Thank you very much for any help!