# cygwin sftp limit user's to home directory

Tags: sftp, cygwin, cygwin-sshd

Is there any way to limit users to certain home directories with sftp and cygwin:

For example user1 cannot get out of

/home/user1/

User2

/home/user2/

I don't think there is on windows but maybe I am wrong.

Failing that is there anyway to only let user's get directory listings and upload files only?  I am trying to avoid users being able to access each other's files.

Thanks

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the sshd_config man page: `man sshd_config`.

It seems that you want the ChrootDirectory option in /etc/sshd_config:

```
ChrootDirectory %h
```

If you only want the restriction to apply to some users, then you should precede the above with

```
Match User user1,user2,...
```

None of the above is specific to Cygwin, but you should test it on Cygwin to be sure that it works as desired there.  I haven't used the ChrootDirectory option myself, so you should check to be sure it's implemented in Cygwin.

Comment: I've done that but I get "connection closed" whenever I have the ChrootDirectory set.  It is not much to go on.

Comment: If you're using public key authentication, try using password authentication instead.  There are limitations on pubkey authentication in Cygwin that might be causing that.

Comment: This answer actually fixed the problem http://serverfault.com/a/201879/65157.  Copssh makes it a bit easier to administer.