# Copssh, Chrootdirectory and spurious cygwin directory

Tags: sftp, cygwin, copssh

I have limited sftp users to their home directory using this answer https://serverfault.com/a/201879/65157.

It all seems to be working fine.  I only have 1 query though.

When I ever issue an 'ls' command, there appears to be an additional cygwindrive directory.  For example I might get a result like this:

```
sftp> ls
cygdrive  five      six
```

Can anyone explain why I might get this?

Thanks

Paul

Answer (score 0):

/cygdrive is the standard prefix where Cygwin puts Windows directories, e.g. /cygdrive/C.  I hadn't seen this before, but it seems that even in a chroot environment, Cygwin wants it to be there.  You can see /cygdrive in /etc/fstab.

This behavior seems to me like a bug in chroot.  I suggest reporting it to the Cygwin mailing list, cygwin@cygwin.com.  Be sure to follow the [problem reporting guidelines](http://cygwin.com/problems.html).